# Quandl Julia error

Tags: package, julia, quandl

I've been experimenting with Quandl in Julia and it works well on the mac, but, alas, Linux not so much. I'm doing really important work and I can't have any hiccups (ok ok I'm just downloading datasets and messing around). For some reason I get this error:

error: readtimearray not defined

It certainly could be a dependencies issue but without a more specific error it's hard for me to remedy.
Here is my code (which does run on my mac sans problems):

using Quandl

bux = quandl("GOOG/NASDAQ_SBUX", rows= 5250)

tail(sbux,2)

println(bux)

Comment: Are you running the same version of julia on each box?

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be with the **version** of `Julia`. Try using **`Julia 0.3.0`** version, it would work with it. Initially I had faced the same problem but solved after updating

[image]

Comment: will do not sure what version I'm running on the linux box. I thought it was 0.3.0 but now I'm not sure. thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Quandl has recently been upgraded to use a more robust downloading mechanism provided by the Requests.jl package. There is also support for two data structures, TimeArrays and DataFrames. You can get the latest `Quandl` by doing

```
julia> Pkg.update()
```

And if you already have it installed you should get the newest better-featured version. The version output from Jay Solanki answer shows the kludgy downloading script that has since been replaced.